# What Redirect from means in react router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I don't know what is the actual meaning of **from** in `<Redirect>` component, also the docs doesn't seem to be useful https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/from-string
Can anybody demonstrate the important cases to use `<Redirect from="/auth" />` ?